# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException crash report

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I got this crash report from many users.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.*appname*/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/com.*appname*-1/pkg.apk
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" on path: /mnt/asec/com.*appname*-1/pkg.apk
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2220)
    ... 11 more
```

Anyone have any idea what to do?

Comment: It means that your app can't find the class called: UnityPlayerActivity, you probably didn't add the Unity engine correctly to your project.

Comment: Can you suggest me what to do??
Then why not every user have a crash?

Comment: I have three plugin in my game and they have different android manifest file. Is there anything wrong that i have done?

Answer (score 0):

Never used unity3d... also I don't know what's in your gradle files, so can't really say unless you give more information. However, you could try cleaning your project and rebuilding it. Go to `Build -> Clean Project` or use `gradlew clean` if you are comfortable with the command line.

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try